# React img src from object

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

How to exract image source from object for img src ?

I have constant defined like this:

```
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  {
    name: "Frozen",
    image: "../../assets/categories/Frozen.png",
    categories: [],
  },
  {
    name: "Baby Care",
    image: "../../assets/categories/BabyCare.png",
    categories: [],
  },
  {
    name: "Bakery",
    image: "../../assets/categories/Bakery.png",
    categories: [],
  },
]
```

I want to map over the array and render a list of each object like the below:

```
  const categories = DUMMY_DATA.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.name} className={classes.category}>
        <img src={item.image} alt="category" />
        <span>{item.name}</span>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className={classes.navBox}>{categories}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
```

unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't really helpful. What is it doing instead? In what way is it failing?

Comment: Your code looks fine, I would guess the paths that are causing the problem. Are you sure `"../../assets/categories/Frozen.png"` is accurate relative to the page the image is displayed on?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What kind of behavior you're seeing, any error messages in your console? Is it just the images not showing up, but everything else is? If that is the case, I would highly suspect a pathing issue.

Comment: It just does not show the pictures.
I tried to import 1 image with the same path
import BabyCare from "../../assets/categories/BabyCare.png";
and it worked so I dont think it's a path issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest importing the images instead of using paths.

```js
import image1 from '../path/image-1.png'
import image2 from '../path/image-2.png'
import image3 from '../path/image-3.png'

const DUMMY_DATA = [
  {
    ...
    image: image1,
  },
  {
    ...
    image: image2,
  },
  {
    ...
    image: image2,
  }
]
```

The reason for this is that when your React application is compiled, the relative paths to access those images will be different.

If you really want to use paths instead of importing, I'd suggest using absolute paths but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67588633-uwcfr) and it seems everything is syntactically correct. Problem seems to exist in the image paths within your dummy data.